# redirect_to path with a specific tab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

A rails controller action, after object creation needs to re-direct to a specific tab on a page  ([generated via the zurb foundation tab facility](https://get.foundation/sites/docs/tabs.html).  The following syntax ignores the tab indentifier

```
redirect_to product_path(@trademark.product), tab: "trademarks"
```

the path `/products/32#trademarks` does render and open properly to the specified tab.

How should the redirect syntax be to make this work as desired?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify `anchor` option for `product_path` method call.

```rb
redirect_to product_path(@trademark.product, anchor: "trademarks")
```

Comment: Just to be precise, it will have to be inserted within the `_path` definition, i.e. not an element of the hash  `format.html { redirect_to product_path(@trademark.product, anchor: "trademarks"), notice: "Trademark was successfully created." }`

Comment: TIL about `anchor`, ty!